# How to build and start a windows 8 metro app from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, msbuild, microsoft-metro

I can successfully batch build the application with 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe TestApplication.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64;DeployOnBuild=true

The problem is how to start it. I can see two potential solutions:

1. Deployed application can be started from the command line or WinApi. The problem is that DeployOnBuild flag seems to be ignored, so the application is built, but not deployed. Is there any way to deploy a metro application, other than using Visual Studio GUI?
2. Maybe there is a way to run an undeployed application? Using a Visual Studio tool for example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the Windows 8 application packages, the build process also creates the powershell script file `Add-AppDevPackage.ps1`. As this is something that can be used for side-loading applications, I'd assume that you could also call this as a part of your process. You should run it manually once first to obtain developer certificate (which will expire after 3 months) and install the app signing certificate, if required. Looking at the script, using a `-Force` parameter should suppress the certificate installation confirmation dialog.

Under the covers the script relies on [`Add-AppxPackage`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856048.aspx) cmdlet.

For starting the application, check out [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/433477/how-do-i-run-a-metro-application-from-the-command-line-in-windows-8).